# Custom drag e drop Javascript não funciona no firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou fazendo um leitor de XML ao qual eu faça o upload de um arquivo e ele leia o conteúdo, no chrome está funcionando tudo ok, porém no firefox por algum motivo o drag e drop não está entrando em `$('#xmlenvio').change(...`, não estou procurando que façam pra mim, só preciso entender o que está acontecendo, pois não gera nenhum erro no console.

Firefox version: 61.0.2 (64-bit)
Chrome version: 69.0.3497.92 (64-bit)

```js
function dropHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var file;

    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
            if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
                document.querySelector('#xmlEnvio').files = ev.dataTransfer.files;
            }
        }
    } 
    removeDragData(ev)
}

function dragOverHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function removeDragData(ev) {
    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
        ev.dataTransfer.items.clear();
    } else {
        ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
    }
}

$('#xmlEnvio').change(function(e){
    alert('chrome works');
    var input = this;
    file = input.files[0];
    $('.form-control.image-preview-filename').val(file.name);
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, "text/xml");
        
        console.log(parsed);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
    console.log('... file[' + 0 + '].name = ' + file.name);
});
```

```css
.upload-drop-zone {
    height: 200px;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.upload-drop-zone {
    color: #ccc;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: #ccc;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center
}

.upload-drop-zone.drop {
    color: #222;
    border-color: #222;
}

.image-preview-input {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;    
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container"> <br />
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <form id="upload" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <strong>Select XML archive</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="input-group image-preview">
                                <input placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled>
                                
                                <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                                    <div class="btn btn-default image-preview-input">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                        <span class="image-preview-input-title">Search</span>
                                        <input id="xmlEnvio" type="file" accept=".xml" name="xml"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-primary">
                                        <span class="btn-label">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        Upload
                                    </button>
                                </span> </div>
                            <br />
                            <div ondrop="dropHandler(event)" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);" class="upload-drop-zone" id="drop-zone">
                                Or drag XML to this area.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Firefox só dispara o evento change se o usuário alterar diretamente o campo `file`, ao contrário do Chrome.

O que você pode fazer é disparar o evento manualmente na função `removeDragData()`, mas isso irá disparar o evento change 2 vezes no Chrome. Para evitar que o evento seja disparado 2 vezes no Chrome, você pode usar uma variável de controle. Se a variável for `true`, a função do evento é ignorada com um `return`, se for `false` executa a função e altera o valor para `true` e um `setTimeout()` de 1 segundo altera novamente para `false`. Desta forma, quando o evento for disparado pela segunda vez irá entrar no `return` e sair da função.

Adicione um trigger no fim da função `removeDragData(ev)`:

```
function removeDragData(ev) {
    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
        ev.dataTransfer.items.clear();
    } else {
        ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
    }

    $('#xmlEnvio').trigger('change');
}
```

Crie uma variável (global) de controle:

```
var mudou;
```

E no início da função do evento change insira 3 linhas que tratam da variável:

```
if(mudou) return;
mudou = true;
setTimeout(function(){ mudou = false }, 1000);
```

No final, o código ficará desta forma:

```
function dropHandler(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var file;

   if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
         if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
            document.querySelector('#xmlEnvio').files = ev.dataTransfer.files;
         }
      }
   } 
   removeDragData(ev)
}

function dragOverHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function removeDragData(ev) {
    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
        ev.dataTransfer.items.clear();
    } else {
        ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
    }

    $('#xmlEnvio').trigger('change');
}

var mudou;

$('#xmlEnvio').change(function(e){

   if(mudou) return;
   mudou = true;
   setTimeout(function(){ mudou = false }, 1000);

    alert('chrome works');
    var input = this;
    file = input.files[0];
    $('.form-control.image-preview-filename').val(file.name);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, "text/xml");

        console.log(parsed);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
    console.log('... file[' + 0 + '].name = ' + file.name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No Firefox, nesse trecho, quando você seta os arquivos no input, o evento não é disparado, já no chrome ele é disparado automaticamente.

```
document.querySelector('#xmlEnvio').files = ev.dataTransfer.files;
```

Para disparar manualmente, você pode usar o seguinte código

```
document.querySelector('#xmlEnvio').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

O problema é que ele disparará duas vezes no Chrome.

Mas lembre-se de que você NÃO precisa usar o input para dar parse nos XMLs. Você pode dar parse diretamente no dropHandler

```
function dropHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const file = ev.dataTransfer.files[0];
    if ( ! file) return;

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, "text/xml");

        console.log('RESULT', parsed);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);

    removeDragData(ev);
}
```

---

**Edição:** Desse jeito você consegue aproveitar o código e funcionar cross-browser :)

```
function parseXML(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, "text/xml");

        console.log('RESULT', parsed);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function dropHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const file = ev.dataTransfer.files[0];
    parseXML(file);
    removeDragData(ev)
}

function dragOverHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function removeDragData(ev) {
    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
        ev.dataTransfer.items.clear();
    } else {
        ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
    }
}

$('#xmlEnvio').change(function(e){
    var input = this;
    const file = input.files[0];
    if ( ! file) return;

    parseXML(file);
});
```

Comment: Eu preciso é que ele fique no onchange por questão de reaproveitamento, pois vou utilizar a função tanto para a questão do drag e drop quanto para quando o cliente seleciona o arquivo

Comment: Quanto ao disparar 2x no chrome eu já havia encontrado uma "solução" desta forma, porém ela não é satisfatória.

Comment: Fácil, crie uma função que se chama "parse" com a leitura do FileReader, e chame-a tanto no dropHandler quanto no onChange do input